# How to factory reset S3 with screen not working but phone working?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, factory-reset, screen

My phone turns on, I hear notifications when I receive SMS (as sound works) but the screen is damaged. Nothing displays at any time and I cannot interact with touch.

I have replaced my damaged phone and wish to factory reset it. How can I do this without the screen displaying? I don't think I can load an app without being able to interact with the display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods in order to factory reset your device:
([Here is the source youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ppkMcOGnAtw))

if your device is working but cant navigate or you got problems with Screen.. then Use the Hardware Method here -> follow the steps here:

1. Hold the **Volume Up** Button with the **Power** Button and the **Home** Button, all at the same time, till you feel your Phone Vibrate. note: You can release the power button after the mobile Vibrate.

   [image: Hold Volume UP with Power Button and the Home Button at the Same Time]
2. After the Menu Appears, Use **Volume Up** and **Down** to Navigate to '**Wipe Data Factory Reset**' then Select it by pressing the **Power** Button.
3. Then Use the **Volume** Buttons Again to Select '**Yes -- delete all user data**' and press the **power** button on it.
4. now just wait tell it finish Wiping, it will just wipe then the menu gets back again, After it gets back just select **Reboot the System**.

If your device is working and its display appears well, follow the the steps here:

1. Go to **Settings**, **Backup and Reset** and select '**Factory data reset**'.
2. Make sure that you made Backup for your data.
3. Press on the '**Reset Device**' Button Appears at Bottom of the Screen.
4. You will have to Confirm your **PIN**, Enter your PIN then go **Next**.
5. Now Confirm your Decisions, if you want to factory reset your phone just Press the **Delete all** Button.

Comment: This is how i verified the reset completed correctly. I connected a usb cable to view the files and recorded with a printscreen. I then booted the phone to get to the system menu. However, when i heard the music of the phone i know i did not hold the 3 keys long enough. 7 seconds did it for me. I used another phone to confirm how many menu clicks were required to reach the options. After i left the phone for a couple of minutes to give enough time for the reset. i booted the phone and found with the usb cable that the files and folders on the phone were much different/reduced. Job done.

Comment: if the screen isnt working you cant see the prompts,or menu,thats the problem